# Process finished with exit code 139, when running dotnet apps

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, debugging

In one of Ubuntu instances all dotnet projects, being built successfully, end with exit code 139 (without any remarks, like "interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV"). Even simple console app `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");`. When I run it in JetBrains Rider with debugger, I get this message:

> One or more errors occurred. (Started a process for debugging, but no CoreCLR runtime was seen to be loaded within the 00:00:16 time limit.)

The fact is, that running dotnet apps in another Ubuntu instanse and in Windows goes successfully, without 139 exit code.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this error?

Comment: @ImranAbdalla not yet